# How to add values from a string in SQL Server 2008 using a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

How can I insert values from a string like this `1,2,3,4;7,3,8,4;3,9,0,4;` into SQL Server 2008 using a stored procedure, where `;` represent a start of new row and `,` represent a new column? e.g the values 1 2 3 4 will be inserted to there respective columns and after ';' the next values i:e 7 3 8 4 will be insert to same columns "7" into first columns and so on

I've found some answers but they've confused me more than ever.

Edit:

Most of the answer i found were inserting values in just two columns by using LTRIM and RTRIM, but i have a varring number of columns on different tables.
I hope this explains my problem

Comment: What do you mean by add them?  What answer did you find that confused you and what was confusing about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have prepared a SQL script for you which splits the input string twice then converts is into row data, and finally inserts into a database table

To split string data, I used this [SQL split string function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-convert-split-delimeted-string-as-rows-using-xml.aspx)
First of all, you need to create this function on your database.

Unfortunately, if you do not use SQL Server 2016 we have to create our split function

I have used [SQL Server CTE query structure](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-multiple-cte-syntax-sql-cte-example-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) to manage all these steps in a single statement instead of using SQL sub-select statements or temp tables.

To understand multiple-CTE structures please refer to above tutorial

I hope it helps
Please check below script on your test database first

```
declare @str varchar(max) = '1,2,3,4;7,3,8,4;3,9,0,4;'

create table stringtorows (id int, col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int)

;with cte as (
select
    id rowid, val rowdata
from dbo.split(@str,';')
where val <> ''
), cte2 as (
select
    rowid, id colid, val coldata
from cte
cross apply dbo.Split(rowdata,',')
), cte3 as (
select
    rowid,
    case when colid = 1 then coldata end col1,
    case when colid = 2 then coldata end col2,
    case when colid = 3 then coldata end col3,
    case when colid = 4 then coldata end col4
from cte2
)
insert into stringtorows
select
    rowid, max(col1) col1, max(col2) col2, max(col3) col3, max(col4) col4
from cte3
group by rowid

select * from stringtorows
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir..i cant tell you how much you have helped me !!!